# Comparisons in Recommendation Letters

Tags: recommendation-letter

I am writing a recommendation for a student for an MS in CS. Can I make comparisons like *'Y is better than X whom I recommended last year and is admitted to your school'* ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't phrase it that way as it denigrates X. But you can certainly make some comparison. "Y reminds me of X." "Both X, who is now your student, and Y have made us proud." "Like X in previous years, Y has become one of our top performers."

Another issue is that you may not know how X is actually doing. I once recommended a student very highly and he did very poorly. He was an excellent student, but was dying of AIDS, which I didn't know.